# Error when submit a <p:pickList> with <p:inputText> column

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need the pickList with a editable column, I'm not sure is it possible.

pickList:

```
<p:pickList value="#{model.formatList}" 
    var="format" 
    itemValue="#{format.formatName}"          
    converter="formatConverter">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{format.formatMess}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{format.width}" />
    </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

In my Backing Bean, all the field in formatList have getter&setter.
When I submit the form,some error message show in console:
    `[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-    1)/page/lookup/lookupFormatEdit.xhtml @91,45 value="#{format.width}" : Target Unreachable,     identifier 'format' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException ...`

But if I replace `<p:inputText value="#{format.width}" />` with `<h:outputText value="#{format.width}" />`, it works.

Anyone could give me some suggestion,thx.

Comment: Even though it's not going to work， I want to know, why this error occur

Comment: Can you post the code for your backing bean? It seems that the page cannot find the bean

Comment: I found a way to instead：Before submit,i use javascript to make the picklist data as JSON format,then backing bean can get the JSON value to update the model.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`<p:pickList>` is simply a list of things for you to pick. I don't think you can have a `<p:inputText>` inside a `<p:pickList>`. I think you should use `<p:dataTable>` with multiple row selection instead. Then you can put `<p:inputText>` in 1 of the columns.

Comment: Yea <p:dataTable> could, but not suitable for my case.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
p:inplace
```

tag of primefaces.

It will work definitely.